# PHP Sublime snippets

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there a way in Sublime to generate a PHP snippets?

Like in VIM, you would use SnipMate

For example, in C, typing

```
for<tab>
```

could be expanded to

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    /* code */
}
```

Comment: Check out their [docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)

Comment: ^ which is literally the first result when googling "sublime text snippets." Come on, people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isntall Sublime Package Control: https://sublime.wbond.net/installation

Then install a snippet manager: https://github.com/csch0/SublimeText-Sublime-Text-3-Snippets

Comment: The snippet manager @tim links to is to help write Sublime3 plugins. Search wbond.net for actual PHP snippets that can be installed and used: https://sublime.wbond.net/search/php%20snippet